# Inheritance and static class members - whats the type of the constructor/class before it's instantiated?

Tags: class, typescript, inheritance, types, static

Completely contrived example incoming - Its the easiest way of explaining whats happening.

I think I may be abstracting at the wrong level *completely*, let me know!

I have an abstract class that many other classes implement. Each class that extends the abstract class has multiple possible identifiers that can be used, so instead of creating a map with many possible values that point to one class, I would like each class to encapsulate their identifiers with static members.

I have a collection of Classes (`Dog`, `Cat`, `Hamster`) that implement some abstract class, `Pet`. These are contained in a utility class `PetIdentifier`. This abstract class `Pet` has a static method with the signature`isNameOk(name: string)`.  Each class that then extends the `Pet` class has a static list of `AcceptableNames`. In the static method, `isNameOk`, I want to be able to check if the name is in the list of acceptable names for that class. I then want to be able to pass to `PetIdentifier`, a name and get back a collection of possible pet classes I can instantiate. Note: I don't want to instantiate until I have done the filtering.

```
class PetIdentifier {
  constructor (private pets: Array<The Pet Class/Constructor Type> = [Dog, Cat, Hamster]) {}
  getPossiblePets (name: string) : Array<The Pet Class/Constructor Type> {
    return this.pets.filter((pet) => pet.isNameOk(name))
  }
}

abstract class Pet {
  private static names: Array<string>
  constructor () {}
  static isNameOk (name: string) : boolean {
    return this.names.indexOf(name) > -1
  }
}

class Dog extends Pet {
  names = ['rex', 'fluffy', 'odin']
}
class Cat extends Pet {
  names = ['fluffy', 'garfield', 'socks']
}
class Hamster extends Pet {
  names = ['thor', 'odin', 'loki']
}

const petIdentifier = new PetIdentifier()
const possiblePetTypes = petIdentifier.getPossiblePets('fluffy')
// instantiate them from here onward and use them
possiblePetTypes.forEach()
```

Comment: I updated my answer to this question with more information if you are interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before we start, you should probably add methods or some distinguishing feature to `Dog`, `Cat`, and `Hamster` (such as `bark()` for `Dog`, `meow()` for `Cat`, and... uh... `spin()` for `Hamster`), so that the TypeScript compiler can tell the difference between them [structurally](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html).

---

You can refer to the static part of the `Pet` class with `typeof Pet`, so the above code will essentially compile with `typeof Pet` in place of `The Pet Class/Constructor Type`.  Unfortunately, you can't instantiate it in your `forEach()` call, since the `Pet` class is abstract:

```
possiblePetTypes.forEach(x => new x()); // error, can't do that
```

---

So the next step is to describe the static side of a constructable subclass of `Pet`:

```
type PetConstructor = {
  new(): Pet;
  isNameOk(name: string): boolean;
}
```

Now you replace `The Pet Class/Constructor Type` with `PetConstructor` and you'll find you *can* instantiate it:

```
possiblePetTypes.forEach(x => new x()); // works fine
```

Done, right?  Well, maybe.  All you know is that `possiblePetTypes` produces an array of `Pet` subclasses, but you have no idea which ones they may be.

---

You can make `PetConstructor` and `PetIdentifier` generic like this:

```
type PetConstructor<P extends Pet> = {
  new(): P;
  isNameOk(name: string): boolean;
}

class PetIdentifier<PC extends PetConstructor<{}>> {
  constructor (private pets: Array<PC>) {}
  getPossiblePets (name: string) : Array<PC> {
    return this.pets.filter((pet) => pet.isNameOk(name))
  }
}
```

(Note that I removed the default value of `[Dog, Cat, Hamster]` in the constructor of `PetIdentifier`, because we might want the generic `PC` to be other types of `Pet`.  We can fix that if we need to).

```
const petIdentifier = new PetIdentifier([Dog, Cat, Hamster])
const possiblePetTypes = petIdentifier.getPossiblePets('fluffy')
possiblePetTypes.forEach(x => new x()); // created Pet is Dog | Cat | Hamster
```

Now you know that the `possiblePetTypes` is `Dog` or `Cat` or `Hamster`.  Done, right?  Maybe, but it sounds like you want to know *at compile time* that `possiblePetTypes` contains `Dog` or `Cat` but *not* `Hamster`, since `'fluffy'` isn't the possible name of a `Hamster`.

---

Well, I don't know of a great way to do that.  TypeScript's control flow analysis isn't anywhere near sophisticated enough to realize that `possiblePetTypes` is narrower, and the static type system isn't quite as full-featured as you'd need to easily express it.  I'd want to use [conditional mapped types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424) so that TypeScript could start building up `Dog | Cat` from examining the type of `Dog.names`, `Cat.names`, and `Hamster.names`.  But it doesn't seem to be there yet.

That's as much as I can do for now.  Hope it helps; good luck!

---

### Update

Since I wrote this, I have played around with the type system and have something which kind of works for inferring the right types.  You may be interested, or you may think it's overkill.  Here is the new code:

First, some helper functions and types:

```
type Lit = string | number | boolean | undefined | null | void | {};
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit, H extends Lit, I extends Lit, J extends Lit, K extends Lit, L extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J, k: K, l: L): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit, H extends Lit, I extends Lit, J extends Lit, K extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J, k: K): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit, H extends Lit, I extends Lit, J extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I, j: J): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit, H extends Lit, I extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H, i: I): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit, H extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G, h: H): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit, G extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F, g: G): [A, B, C, D, E, F, G];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit, F extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E, f: F): [A, B, C, D, E, F];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit, E extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D, e: E): [A, B, C, D, E];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit, D extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D): [A, B, C, D];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit, C extends Lit>(a: A, b: B, c: C): [A, B, C];
function tuple<A extends Lit, B extends Lit>(a: A, b: B): [A, B];
function tuple<A extends Lit>(a: A): [A];
function tuple(...args: any[]): any[] {
  return args;
}

type Constructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
  readonly prototype: T;
}

type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[K in T]: K} &
  {[K in U]: never} & { [K: string]: never })[T];
```

Now for the heavy lifting.  I changed all the static methods/properties to instance methods/properties.  This may not be what you want, but it's much easier to manipulate the types this way.  If you like this method and still need static methods, you can probably do it, but it would be even more tedious.

```
abstract class Pet {
  names: string[];
  constructor() {}
  isNameOk(name: string): boolean {
    return this.names.indexOf(name) > -1;
  }
  ["constructor"]: Constructor<this>;
  nameMap: Record<string, Pet> &
    Record<this['names'][number], this> &
    Record<Diff<AllPets['names'][number], this['names'][number]>, never> = null!;
    // type helper, just null at runtime
}
```

Note that I added a `nameMap` property which is just null at runtime.  TypeScript uses it though to maintain a mapping from each possible pet name to the type of pet.

```
class PetIdentifier<P extends Pet> {
  constructor (private pets: Array<P>) {}
  getPossiblePets<N extends string>(name: N) : Array<P['nameMap'][N]> {
    return this.pets.filter((pet) => pet.isNameOk(name))
  }
}
```

And now `getPossiblePets()` returns an array of only the relevant type of pet.

```
class Dog extends Pet {
  names = tuple('rex', 'fluffy', 'odin') //  use tuple for literals
  bark() { }
}
class Cat extends Pet {
  names = tuple('fluffy', 'garfield', 'socks')
  meow() { }
}
class Hamster extends Pet {
  names = tuple('thor', 'odin', 'loki')
  spin() { }
}
type AllPets = Dog | Cat | Hamster; // need an AllPets type
```

Note that I used the `tuple()` helper function to declare the `names` properties; this allows `names` to be inferred as a tuple of string literals instead of a string array.  TypeScript needs the string literals to do the mapping.

Also note I need the `AllPets` type, which is the explicit union of all declared subclasses of `Pet`.  This is needed up in the `nameMap` property of `Pet`, so that that, say, `Cat` knows about the name, say, `thor` and can answer "no" when asked if a `Cat` can be named `thor`.  (No, there's no way to set it up so that `Cat` can say "no" to any name it doesn't recognize).

Finally, the results:

```
const petIdentifier = new PetIdentifier([new Dog(), new Cat(), new Hamster()]);
const possiblePetTypes = petIdentifier.getPossiblePets('fluffy')
// possible pet types is (Dog | Cat)[], no Hamster!
```

See how `possiblePetTypes` no longer includes `Hamster`.

If you give it a completely random name, like:

```
const impossiblePetTypes = petIdentifier.getPossiblePets('galactus');
// impossiblePetTypes is Pet[]
```

It will return the generic `Pet[]` type.  No, I can't get it to return something like `never[]`, sorry.

Okay, that kind of works and is totally crazy and might not be maintainable by anyone.  I guess I'd recommend just giving up on knowing at design time what types of `Pet` come out of `getPossiblePets()`, and just live with the fact that this is the kind of thing that is better dealt with at runtime.  If you pass in a string whose value is not known at design time:

```
declare const someName: string;
const possiblePetTypes = petIdentifier.getPossiblePets(someName); // Pet[]
```

then you get zero benefit from all this type juggling.  So, yeah.  Treat the above as a fun diversion, but I'd be loath to try it for anything you care about deploying to some kind of production system.  Good luck again!